# return only part of Whois information

Tags: node.js, whois

Hi we are trying to use NodeJS to return IP address WHOIS information before we send the requesting IP address to the rest of our app - That part is easy.

However the part that is not easy is, selecting only the `Organization` part of the whois information.

for example this is a whois and what it returns

```
whois 137.184.236.168
% IANA WHOIS server
% for more information on IANA, visit http://www.iana.org
% This query returned 1 object

refer:        whois.arin.net

inetnum:      137.0.0.0 - 137.255.255.255
organisation: Administered by ARIN
status:       LEGACY

whois:        whois.arin.net

changed:      1993-05
source:       IANA

# whois.arin.net

NetRange:       137.184.0.0 - 137.184.255.255
CIDR:           137.184.0.0/16
NetName:        DIGITALOCEAN-137-184-0-0
NetHandle:      NET-137-184-0-0-1
Parent:         NET137 (NET-137-0-0-0-0)
NetType:        Direct Allocation
OriginAS:       AS14061
Organization:   DigitalOcean, LLC (DO-13)
RegDate:        2019-11-13
Updated:        2020-04-03
Comment:        Routing and Peering Policy can be found at https://www.as14061.net
Comment:        
Comment:        Please submit abuse reports at https://www.digitalocean.com/company/contact/#abuse
Ref:            https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/137.184.0.0



OrgName:        DigitalOcean, LLC
OrgId:          DO-13
Address:        101 Ave of the Americas
Address:        FL2
City:           New York
StateProv:      NY
PostalCode:     10013
Country:        US
RegDate:        2012-05-14
Updated:        2022-05-19
Ref:            https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/DO-13


OrgAbuseHandle: ABUSE5232-ARIN
OrgAbuseName:   Abuse, DigitalOcean 
OrgAbusePhone:  +1-347-875-6044 
OrgAbuseEmail:  abuse@digitalocean.com
OrgAbuseRef:    https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/ABUSE5232-ARIN

OrgTechHandle: NOC32014-ARIN
OrgTechName:   Network Operations Center
OrgTechPhone:  +1-347-875-6044 
OrgTechEmail:  noc@digitalocean.com
OrgTechRef:    https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/NOC32014-ARIN

OrgNOCHandle: NOC32014-ARIN
OrgNOCName:   Network Operations Center
OrgNOCPhone:  +1-347-875-6044 
OrgNOCEmail:  noc@digitalocean.com
OrgNOCRef:    https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/NOC32014-ARIN
```

The only thing we are interested in is `Organization:   DigitalOcean, LLC (DO-13)`

As we want to drop all IP addresses from this host provider.

We noticed that we have been successful at stopping Google and AWS via using `host` command but Digital Ocean does not work this way and we need to do it via Whois.

I know in NodeJS I would request the information

```
 exec("whois "+ip, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(stdout);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use a regular expression:

```js
const organizationPattern = /^organization:\s*(.+)$/im;
const match = organizationPattern.exec(stdout);
const organization = match ? match[1] : 'unknown';

console.log(organization);
```